# How to find the percentage of ASTM type distribution of cast iron using image processing using openCV in C++?

Tags: opencv, image-processing, visual-c++

I have a microscopic image of cast iron which is used in the foundry industry. This image contains different types of flakes.[Example image of cast iron image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/plgwS.jpg). Now I want to find the size of flakes and distribute them according to their types. I have a pre-defined image of all five types. [Different types of flake](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ak1R7.png). I just want to find that in the first image how many flakes are of type A, how many flakes are of type B and likewise. So, is there any algorithm in OpenCV to do this. [Report of what I want to do](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YiE3C.png). I am implementing this project in VC++ using openCV.

Thanks in advance

Comment: There is no complete solution for your task in OpenCV. From my point of view, this will be an advanced image processing project.

Comment: It's okay if the solution is other than openCV.

Comment: I'm afraid, you don't understand me: This task - independent from the general approach (plain image processing, deep learning), tool kit, or programming language, etc. - will be A LOT OF WORK. So, YOU should start by thinking about a general pipeline, how to achieve your goal, identify single steps needed, implementing stuff, and so on. If you then(!) encounter _specific_ problems in terms of _programming_, you can ask _specific_ questions on Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 0):

You need to collect lots of images for each type of flake. Put them in separate classes and train them using tensorflow for classification. Once you train your model, your model will be able to take a new image and give out detections and classify the detections and you can write an algorithm to count the different types and make a report. [This](https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/keras/basic_classification) can be a good starting point.